# Transposing single cell with multiple lines across horizontally into individual cells

Tags: google-sheets

I need each line in this one cell to be transposed into individual cells along the same row.

I used to be able to use something like this:

```
=split(regexreplace(R2, "(.{10})", "/$1"),"/")
```

Now I can't seem to get it

[image: example data set]

Answer (score 0):

```
=split(A1,Char(10))
```

(I am not prepared to type in all of the numbers OP could not be bothered to present as text just to show the above works, nor guess what underlies the `#REF!`.)